# Marketing cloud sandbox integration with Salesforce sandbox using V5 marketing cloud connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to integrate Marketing cloud sandbox with salesforce sandbox using V5 marketing cloud connector, i have followed all the steps involved in the documentation for integration ([Integration Documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/review_prerequisites_and_install_package/prerequisites/) but still i am getting the following error

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: As per conversation with MC support MC sandbox doesn't support marketing cloud connect. That means we cannot integrate with sales cloud